# How to make a original image alpha gradient?

Tags: iphone, image, gradient, alpha, coverflow

I am using coverflow and I want to make the image's shadow in the coverflow gradiently alpha. For example, the alpha at the top of the image would be 0.5, and at the bottom of image it would be 1. I can not use gradient background view.

Answer (score 0):

Use CAGradientLayer for that purpose. [Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: hi,brother,CAGradientLayer seems only can put a new Layer on the image,but now my whole iphone screen background is clearColor,so how can I implement my purpose above? thanks all the time!